# NameError: 'c' is not defined

Tags: python

I write below code in python(version 3.6.2):

```
def test():
    temp = 'c=1'
    exec(temp)
    print(c)

test()
```

when run it, I get below error:

```
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

but when  run below code :

```
temp='a=1'
exec(temp)
print(a)
```

it print 1.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You don't have a variable called c how you would print it?, print(c) raise the error.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error in python2.7 or python3.  It prints `1` each time.

Comment: I'm also unable to repro...

Comment: it's not error for me

Comment: I've reproduced it in Python 3.6.1.

Comment: The documentation on Python 3's [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is pretty clear: *"modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns."* (globals is a different story)

Comment: Also, you *almost certainly* don't want to be using `exec` to dynamically assign variables. There is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The exec() function can only be followed by a string or an object. What you asked it to do is not one of those. You should try just defining c in another way or stop using exec()

Comment: Huh? OP passes a string, the problem isn't that, it's that `exec` does not modify `locals`